# Set axis limits in matplotlib but autoscale within them

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to set the max and min values of an axis in matplotlib, but then autoscale when the values are much smaller than these limits?

For example, I want a graph of percentage change to be limited between -100 and 100, but many of my plots will be between, say, -5 and 5. When I use `ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)`, this graph is very unclear.

I suppose I could use something like `ax.set_ylim(max((-100, data-n)), min((100, data+n)))`, but is there a more built in way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no built-in way for outlier detection of the scales. Either you set the limits, or you don't. (Only exception, you can set one of the limits, and let the other autoscale, but that's of no use in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ImportanceOfBeingErnest [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520064/set-axis-limits-in-matplotlib-but-autoscale-within-them#comment95843550_54520064), there is no support for this feature.  In the end I just used my original idea, but scaled it by the value of the max and min to give the impression of autoscale.

```
ax.set_ylim(max((-100, data_min+data_min*0.1)), min((100, data_max+data_max*0.1)))
```

Where for my case it is true that

```
data_min <= 0, data_max >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop extreme outliers you could use the numpy [`quantile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) function to find say the first 0.001 % of the data and last 99.999 %.

```
near_min = np.quantile(in_data, 0.0001)
near_max = np.quantile(in_data, 0.9999)
ax.set_ylim(near_min, near_max)
```

You will need to adjust the quantile depending on the volume of data you drop. You might want to include some test of whether the difference between near_min and true min is significant?

Comment: Sorry my link didn't work: [quantile function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html)

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately for my data I can't be sure that I will capture all outliers with any set percentage of data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set axis limits based on range of the data each time plot is updated?

```
ax.set_ylim(min(data), max(data))
```

Or check if range of data is below some threshold, and then set axis limits.

```
if min(abs(data)) < thresh:
    ax.set_ylim(min(data), max(data))
```

Comment: I want to limit the axis to a certain level in the case of extreme outliers. If I used the min and max and there was a value of 100000 the rest of the graph would be meaningless.